# How select last row of a rowgroup

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

My [table with rowgroups](http://live.datatables.net/xufuxeta/1/edit).

How can I show only the inner borders for the rowgroup?
At the moment the table shows no left/right/top border as wanted, but I don't know how I can select the last row of the rowgroup.

**Borders that aren't needed:**

[image: Image of the borders which are not needed]

```css
div {
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.dataTable,
table.dataTable th,
table.dataTable td {
  box-sizing: border-box ! important;
}

.tg {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  border: none ! important;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td,
th {
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px ! important;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg tr td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  border-left: none ! important;
}

.tg tr td:last-child,
th:last-child {
  border-right: none ! important;
}

.tg tr td,
th {
  border-right: none ! important;
  border-top: none ! important;
}

.tg tr th {
  border-bottom: none ! important;
}

.tg thead tr:last-child th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid ! important;
}

.tg .header-left {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border-color: inherit;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  will-change: transform;
}

.tg .header-center {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border-color: inherit;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  will-change: transform;
}

.tg .header-right {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border-color: inherit;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  will-change: transform;
}

.tg .cell-left {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tg .cell-center {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tg .cell-right {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="tg wrap stripe" id="tableData">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="header-left">Name</th>
        <th class="header-left">Position</th>
        <th class="header-center">Age</th>
        <th class="header-center">Start date</th>
        <th class="header-right">Salary</th>
        <th class="header-">Office</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="cell-left">Airi Satou</td>
        <td class="cell-left">Accountant</td>
        <td class="cell-center">33</td>
        <td class="cell-center">28-Nov-2008</td>
        <td class="cell-right">$162,700</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="cell-left">Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td class="cell-left">Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td class="cell-center">47</td>
        <td class="cell-center">09-Oct-2009</td>
        <td class="cell-right">$1,200,000</td>
        <td>London</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following selector is what I would use:

```css
.table tr:last-child th, 
.table tr:last-child td{
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, 
I tried it, but only the last table row is selected and not each last row of the rowgroup.

Comment: border-bottom: none;

Comment: It is much easier to get the first row after row group with `table tr.dtrg-group + tr td {border-top: none ! important;}` The issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to get the first row after row group:

```css
table tr.dtrg-group + tr td {
  border-top: none ! important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS rule should remove your unwanted border:

```css
tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Below is a refactored version of your CSS. Less is ALWAYS more, don't set properties to their default values, i.e. `font-weight: normal` is useless because font weight is already normal, just remove it, unclutter your CSS. Don't `border-color: inherit` if you're not drawing a border etc.

```css
.container {
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.tg {
  all: unset;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0.5em 0.2em;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header-left,
.cell-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.header-center,
.cell-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.header-right,
.cell-right {
  text-align: right;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="tg wrap stripe" id="tableData">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="header-left">Name</th>
        <th class="header-left">Position</th>
        <th class="header-center">Age</th>
        <th class="header-center">Start date</th>
        <th class="header-right">Salary</th>
        <th class="header-">Office</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="cell-left">Airi Satou</td>
        <td class="cell-left">Accountant</td>
        <td class="cell-center">33</td>
        <td class="cell-center">28-Nov-2008</td>
        <td class="cell-right">$162,700</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="cell-left">Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td class="cell-left">Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td class="cell-center">47</td>
        <td class="cell-center">09-Oct-2009</td>
        <td class="cell-right">$1,200,000</td>
        <td>London</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```